# Trouble Adding User to Keycloak Container Linked to PostgreSQL Container via Admin REST API in Spring Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, registration

I'm developing an e-commerce web app using Spring Boot, and Keycloak is responsible for user registration, authentication, and authorization. Keycloak is connected to a PostgreSQL container for data storage. The problem arises during user registration, where the process seemingly completes without errors, but the user is not added. I've validated the credentials multiple times, and they don't seem to be the cause. Additionally, I've experimented with different grant types, including OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD and Client Credentials, without success. Strangely, when I create a user directly via the Keycloak admin console, it works fine, and the user is visible in the database. However, when attempting to register a user through the application, the user is not visible in the Keycloak users section or the database. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Here is the KeycloakConfig I am using:

```
@Configuration
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    private static Keycloak keycloak = null;

    @Value("${keycloak.auth-server-url}")
    private String authServerUrl;

    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    private String realm;

    @Value("${keycloak.resource}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${keycloak.credentials.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;



    public Keycloak getInstance() {
        if (keycloak == null) {
            keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                    .serverUrl(authServerUrl)
                    .realm(realm)
                    .clientId(clientId)
                    .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .username("admin@gmail.com")
                    .password("123")
                    .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                    .build();
        }
        return keycloak;
    }
}
```

And here is the method which is responsible for user creation:

```
@Transactional
    public void createUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
        try{
            CredentialRepresentation credential = Credentials
                    .createPasswordCredentials(userDTO.password());
            UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
            user.setFirstName(userDTO.firstName());
            user.setUsername(userDTO.email());
            user.setLastName(userDTO.lastName());
            user.setEmail(userDTO.email());
            user.setCredentials(Collections.singletonList(credential));
            user.setEnabled(true);
            user.setEmailVerified(true);

            UsersResource instance = keycloakConfig.getInstance().realm(realm).users();
            instance.create(user);
            System.out.println("CREATED USER");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // Log or handle the exception appropriately
            throw new RuntimeException("USER CREATION FAILED");
        }

    }
```

At the end it just prints "CREATED USER"